# HTML service error creating elements dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working with html service of google-apps-script and I'm writing some modules to make life easier. The module below its designed to create elements fast and easy with an easy to read notation.

All works fine except the text function. It uses the input function to create a specific input type. In this case, a text one. When I try to use it I get the following error:

> Untaming of guest constructed objects unsupported

I can't understand this error. Could anyone explain it to me?

```
 var util = {
 create: (function(){

     var element = function (elementName,atributes ){
              var element = $(  document.createElement(elementName)  );
              return atributes ?  element.attr(atributes) : element;
          },

     div = function(atributes){ return element('div',atributes); },
     textArea = function(atributes){ return element('textarea',atributes); },
     input = function(atributes){ return element('input',atributes); },
     text = function(atributes){ 
         atributes.type = "text";
         return input(atributes); 
     };

     return { div:div, input : input, text:text, textArea:textArea}

 })()

 };
```